# How to do index based form validation in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array, I am mapping that array into input fields(SelectInput), I can do form validation if the values are known, but in array input fields are dynamic, can any one help me or can give me an idea how to do form validation in array-based input form?

```
state = {
    values: {},
    errors: {}
};
```

populated state(Here keys inside value is code)

```
 state = {
    values: {
        color: "colorValue",
        memory: "memoryValue"
    }
}
```

array

```
[
    {
        code: 'memory',
        name: 'Memory',
    },
    {
        code: 'color',
        name: 'color',
    },
],
```

mapping of array into input feilds

```
{arrayValue.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <InputCtr key={index}>
            <InputCtr>
                <Label>{item && item.name}</Label>

                <EachInput>
                    <SelectInput
                        options={axisOptions}
                        value={values[item.code]}
                        onChange={value => this.dropdownChange(value, item.axisCode)}
                        placeholder={'Select Axis'}
                    />
                </EachInput>
            </InputCtr>
        </InputCtr>
    );
})}
```

Comment: Can you show what a populated `state` would look like?

Comment: Assuming you can show an error for an individual input field if you get a new error. You do `setState({ errors: {...previousState.errors, [code]: 'Error description'}}`. Basically the idea is don't use array indexes instead use the `code` assuming it's unique. That way it'll be easier to remove and add errors without worrying about indexes and with constant access times.

Comment: hey @Martin have added the populated state in post description

Comment: @kimobrian254, u mean to say that i have to do set state in dropdown onchange function ?

Comment: @wali, yes that's like a callback function and it's perfectly ok to set state there. So something like `onChange={(text) => if(typeof text !== 'number') setState({ errors: {...previousState.errors, [item.code]: 'Should be a number'}}` . I'm taking an example if you want numbers only